# Internet of Things - How to initially connect the device?

Tags: configuration, network-protocols

When thinking about the "internet of things", I am imagining a home appliance that needs to connect to the home Wi-Fi and from there one can use their smartphone to control the appliance. This should remove the need for any interface of the devide (USB / LCD / etc). But how would you initially connect this device to the internet? you need some initial configuration. It make no sense to have, say, a USB interface used for initial configuration, i.e. a one-time only job. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All devices will require some sort of user I/O to configure WiFi. This is unavoidable, but can be simplified through some other method like you had mentioned. A reliable option would be to connect to the device via bluetooth to configure it, and then have it rely on WiFi afterward.

You may also want to take a look at how Google does it for the Chromecast. First, the Chromecast broadcasts its own WiFi signal for the user to connect to. It then uses the app to configure the WiFi. When complete, the device reboots and connects to the signal as configured by the user. Now there is no need for external interfaces (LCD, USB) and you can use the same smartphone application to configure it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helps, but I wonder whether what the chromecast does requires any special features, other than standard microcontroller with Wi-Fi support...Because here you're broadcasting, not only connecting!

Comment: It's quite simple to broadcast a WiFi signal. There are small modules that work with microcontrollers to do so, and many have them built in. A lot of receivers are also transmitters.